# Can I reuse same variables in multiple New Relic widgets?

Tags: newrelic

I have a list of relevant IDs that I want to reuse for different queries. Is there a way to specify them and reuse them in each of the queries/widgets or do I have to copy them each time?

E.g. I'd like to avoid specifying client ids and their names in each query

```
SELECT * from Transaction where appName='appname' and client_id IN ('1', '2')  
facet cases(where client_id = '1' as 'Client1', where client_id = '2' as 'Client2') timeseries 1 minute SINCE 5 hours ago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that can be achieved using the UI to craft NRQL queries, but there is a way to do this. You can do this programmatically using [NerdGraph](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/nerdgraph/get-started/introduction-new-relic-nerdgraph/).